# Monitor recommendation for programmer

Tags: monitors, development

I am looking for a computer monitor. I am a software developer so it will be displaying a static picture almost all the time. I don't play games or play very rarely so I don't care about this. Besides this: Internet, sometimes some movie.

I already had some reading so I have the following requirements:

- ca. 24 in
- up to $500 but very happy to pay not more than $300
- FullHD or WUXGA
- not TN or VA
- good viewing angle
- good black representation
- no bright too much and flicker-free-like function
- anti-glare or similar

The only candidate I have for now is  [Eizo FS EV2455](http://www.eizo.com/products/flexscan/ev2455/) but it would be very nice if it were a bit cheaper...

Comment: Why not VA? They have very good black levels and high contrast. I have two different types that also have very wide viewing angles and very good color representation. And with the quick response time (and one is 120Hz) they even are good for gaming. For me they were the all round monitor of choice. Even for non-gamers something to consider.

Comment: @bpiec I think "Ergonomic Height & Tilt Adjustable" is important for developers, if you agree, add this feature to your question. also full port is important feature (such as HDMI, DisplayPort, VGA, and DVI ) for connection to some devices.

Comment: @jazZRo: very bad response time and bad angles.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari: of course I agree with you but these (for me) are just "nice to have" and not "required".

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this [BenQ GW2765HT](https://m.newegg.com/products/N82E16824014383)
 monitor for awhile now and love it. It's a 27 inch 1440p display that's at the sweet spot of size and resolution and price (at the moment).

They have a 24" model that I'd assume is just as capable in the smaller size [BenQ GW2480](https://m.newegg.com/products/24-014-466?iscoz=true)